# Get DATETIME in php and post it to MySQL for transaction consistency

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, transactions, innodb

Here is a link to the reason behind this question:
[NOW() for DATETIME InnoDB Transaction guaranteed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113317/now-for-datetime-innodb-transaction-guaranteed)

So to ensure a single transaction with any number of queries (**20+** queries for example) has a 100% **accurate and consistent NOW()** value accross multiple tables, what is the php way to assign a variable equivalent of DATETIME using NOW() (not current TIMESTAMP).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One way could be:

```
<?php
$nowFormat = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$sql = "INSERT INTO table SET field='$nowFormat'";
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO table SET field='$nowFormat'";
...
```

Comment: Be careful if the PHP server and Mysql server do not have the same default timezone. See my answer for an alternative without this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Do it in MySQL, so you don't involve PHP at all:

```
select @now := now();

insert into .... values (@now)
select from ... where x=@now
etc....
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
<?
$now = time();
$sql = "INSERT INTO table SET field=FROM_UNIXTIME($now)";
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO table SET field=FROM_UNIXTIME($now)";
...
```

This avoids any possible issues of timezones, or local date formats.